# Como deixar os oceanos em branco no basemap?

Tags: python-3.x, map

O código seguinte produz um mapa com um esquema de cores. Eu preciso que as cores fiquem apenas sobre os continentes, deixando os oceanos em branco. Como consigo isto?
Ficheiro excel : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z3YCMyGRqX8q7TNC3w6BkDw2cuN2E0_P7W42syGmz7s/edit#gid=1183595729

```
dados=['meteo_model.xlsx']    #vai buscar os dados ao ficheiro excel
sheets=['Longitude (deg)','Latitude (deg)','Pressure (hPa)','Temperature (K)','qv (g kg^-1)','W (m s^-1)','V (m s^-1)','U (m s^-1)','Rain (mm)'
    ,'Elevation (m)']
nvar=len(sheets)
wb=pyxl.load_workbook(dados[0]) 


ivar=0 
for variable in sheets: 
ws=wb[variable]
if variable=='Longitude (deg)': 
    rows=ws.max_row        #identifica dimensao da worksheet
    cols=ws.max_column
    var=np.zeros((rows,cols,nvar))
for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
            var[r,c,ivar]=ws.cell(row=r+1,column=c+1).value        
ivar=ivar+1
lon=var[:,:,0];lat=var[:,:,1]; qv = var [:,:,3] - 273.15

plt.figure()
mymap = Basemap(height = 1.2e6, width = 1.2e6, resolution = 'l', area_thresh = 0.1, projection = 'tmerc',lon_0= -5,lat_0 = 40)
mymap.drawcoastlines(linewidth = 1)
mymap.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,360,5),labels = [False,False,False,True])
mymap.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,5),labels = [True,False,False,False])
x , y = mymap(lon,lat)



mymap = mymap.pcolormesh(x,y,qv,cmap='jet')
```

Comment: Esta no **SOpt**, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/291797/edit) e traduza sua pergunta!

Comment: Erro meu, o google redirecionou-me automaticamente para o português!

Comment: Já está feito, obrigado!

Comment: Seria interessante, e ajudaria o pessoal se você explicar melhor aonde esta seu problema, se possivel adicionar um trecho do arquivo **meteo_model.xlsx**, para poder testar o código.. Veja: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Como coloco um ficheiro excel aqui?

Comment: Se possível copie algumas colunas e adicione um link usando *Google Docs*, etc.